# Marketing Cloud Automated Email Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, automation, marketingcloudapi

We are wanting to create a solution within the Marketing Cloud that essentially allows us to input a SubjectLine and Body into a CloudPage, have that CloudPage update our data extension with those values for all rows, and then fires an immediate email. It's for when we have emergency system downtime. We would have a single person (admin) fill out this form and submit in hopes that it would automatically send to all employees. Here is what I have created and working so far:

1. Data Extension called 'Employees' that contains the following fields: Email, SubjectLine, Body. All employees are imported into this data extension with blank SubjectLine and Body values.
2. Landing page that captures two fields: SubjectLine and Body.
3. Processing page that loops through each record that exists in the data extension and populates SubjectLine and Body for them all.

** This is all working **

What I need now is how can I trigger an automated email from this? We are just wanting a way to quickly populate this CloudPage with the SubjectLine and Body, and have it communicate with our user-base in an automated fashion when we have system downtime with our custom applications.

In my head, I'd like it to be so that when the data extension is updated with the new SubjectLine and Body values it fires off my email (which has personalization to automatically input the SubjectLine and Body values). I just cannot think of how I could do this.

Comment: I would consider an automation with a single email activity, configured to utilise your sendable data extension. This will also allow you to place additional data processing or notifications into the automation if needed, at a later stage.

Comment: Automation studio only can run every hour at its quickest, unless I am misunderstanding your solution. We would need this to fire off the email once the landing page data has been submitted.

Comment: Generally speaking, you need to build a handler cloudpage that accepts an API call from your webform.
That handler page can, again via API / alternatively WSProxy, trigger a Triggered Send, or start an automation that contains a user initiated send.  The email in that would contain dynamic variables that you send along with your webform input.
You want that service to have an authentication mechanism or you will construct a public API.  Not rocket science, but if you start from scratch, this is all easier said than done.

Comment: @JonasLamberty I appreciate that. I am still learning the custom development / API side of things, so bear with me. I have a processing page already created that uses AMP to upsert the data from the form into my data extension. Does this handler page need to be separate or included within that same processing page? Does it replace my ampscript or is it an add-on? Sorry for being a newbie, but would appreciate any sort of clarification - thanks in advance!

Comment: @JohnBrazas [here](https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-start-status-of-automation-from-marketingcloud-form/) and [here](https://ampscript.com/how-to-run-automations-more-frequently-using-ssjs/) are guides explaining how to start an automation from e.g. a cloud page using ssjs. You should be able to reuse much of the code there, to put in your handler page.

Comment: What you call "processing page" is what I called "handler". So, not separate. You'll have to custom code / add to it. You CAN use AMPscript, but don't. Once it comes near API calls, SSJS will be where it's at.